# Fusion Auth /api/jwt/issue api not working as expected

Tags: jwt, refresh-token, fusionauth

I am calling /api/jwt/issue api to generate a new auth and refresh token for a user. I am not able to make the request from postman if the cookies are disabled.

I always get a 401. I checked and I have the Authorization set in the headers. The API key has the permission to call the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

The JWT Issue API does not accept an API key. The only way to call this API is with a valid JWT. This API is used to exchange a valid JWT for another one in a different application.

You can review the valid ways to call this API in the [JWT Issue documentation.](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/jwt#issue-a-jwt)

Comment: Okay, What is the best way to refresh a refresh token and auth token? I was under the impression that this API will help me do that. I could not find an API to get a new refresh token.

Comment: In order to get a new refresh token, the user will need to log in again (or provide the username, password and application Id which you can then use with the Login API). See https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/tutorials/json-web-tokens#refresh-tokens for more information.

Comment: Based on the security needs of your application, you can set the lifetime of your refresh tokens (see the `application.jwtConfiguration.refreshTokenTimeToLiveInMinutes` setting here: https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/applications) , but you can't get a new one without the user providing their credentials again.

Comment: Thanks guys! this helped